# PHP: How can I get this value?

Tags: php

```
$result2 = $db->prepare('SELECT `lkey_member` FROM mxscript_slayer_licensekeys WHERE `lkey_key` = ?');
$result2->bindParam(1, $auth);
$result2->execute();
```

How can I print the value of `lkey_member` from result2?

Comment: Have you read the documentation about PDO?

Comment: yeah, i'm still confused though, i'm a really newb with php

Comment: How about http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php ?

Comment: Skimmed over it, is that necessary though?

Comment: is it necessary what? There is an example of how to fetch data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First fetch it, then [echo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) it. In this case you can use the [fetchColumn](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php) function [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) has by specifying the index of the column you want to fetch (in this case the only one you are retrieving):

```
$lKeyMember = $result2->fetchColumn(0);


echo $lKeyMember;
```

Answer (score 0):

As from http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

```
/* Exercise PDOStatement::fetch styles */
//..print("PDO::FETCH_ASSOC: ");
//..print("Return next row as an array indexed by column name\n");
$result = $result2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print_r($result);
```

> $result[0] may be helpful